# Draw tree of SQL joins

Tags: sql, join, oracle-sqldeveloper, visualization

When I add a join error (like removing the "on") in a join statement in SQL Developer, I get a hint saying my table *is disconnected from the rest of the join graph*, along with a tree display (the join graph) of the different joins, like :

```
from
          table1
left join child1oftable1         on table1.field1         = child1oftable1.field1
left join child2oftable1         on table1.field2         = child2oftable1.field1
left join child1ofchild1oftable1 on child1oftable1.field2 = child1ofchild1oftable1.field1
```

and the tree visualisation :

```
Table1
    Child1OfTable1
        Child1OfChild1OfTable1
    Child2Oftable1
```

Is there any way to get a simple graph like this from a SQL request (without introducing "disconnected" tables in my joins) ? Can be in SQL or with a tool like SQLDeveloper.

Comment: I think you need to use the connect by loop, this article will help: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_advanced_sql_connect_by_loop.htm

Comment: Isn't this "connect by" a tool to make hierarchical queries on database data ? I want to extract information directly from the query I'm writing, not the data : extract the joins hierarchy within the query itself. Cheers :)